# UpdateLink macro works in developer mode but doesn't work from button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple macro which updates the values from an external file which is on OneDrive. Like this:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:= _
    "https://d.docs.live.net/xxxxx/yyyyyy/MyFile.xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks
End Sub
```

** *xxxxx and yyyyy are just placeholders*

When I run this sub in VBA it works perfectly but when I assign this to a button and click, macro runs but somehow can't retrieve the values. And gives this error:

[image: vba updatelink error]

What can be the reason and any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Silly question but are you assigning the button to the same Workbook because you are using `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: @TimWilkinson Nice try but I tried `ThisWorkbook` but doesn't work either. I also recorded macro. It runs from developer but not from button. Weird!